# Proving $\frac{\sqrt3\cos x-\sin x}{\sin 3x}> \frac{\sqrt3}{3x}-\frac13$ for small $x>0$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Prove that$$\frac{\sqrt3\cos x-\sin x}{\sin 3x}> \frac{\sqrt3}{3x}-\frac13$$
>   for small $x$ near $0$.

From Taylor expansion I can see that $$\frac{\cos x}{\sin3x}>\frac13x,\quad \frac{\sin x}{\sin3x}>\frac13,$$ but combining these two does not give actually what I want. I kindly thank you anyone that can provide at least an idea. I know this is true graphically but I want to see rigorously.

Comment: The Maple command series((sqrt(3)*cos(x)-sin(x))/sin(3*x)-(1/3)*sqrt(3)*x+1/3, x, 2); outputs ${\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3}}{x}^{-1}+O \left( x \right) . $ Therefore, the inequality is true for small positive values of $x$ and false for small negative values of $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much for Martin and user64496. I noticed that I did a typo on the right side the inequality the first term should be sqrt(3)/(3x).

Comment: $$\dfrac{\sqrt3\cos x-\sin x}{\sin3x}=\dfrac{2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi3-x\right)}{\sin3\left(\dfrac\pi3-x\right)}$$

Comment: (I second lab bhattacharjee's comment at 2018-03-08 07:25:07Z. The identity is true for every $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{k\frac{\pi}{3}\colon k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.)

Comment: @user101496 I have edited $\frac{\sqrt3}3x$ to $\frac{\sqrt3}{3x}$ - if I understand your comment that [you left on the MO version - before migration](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/294664/timeline#comment_731441) this is what you intended to ask. Please check whether now the statement of the problem is correct - and if needed, edit the post further to get it to the form you want to sak.

Comment: @user101496 : What *Martin Sleziak* says makes indeed much more sense. Then you get $\sqrt{3}\cos x  - \sin x - \frac{1}{3}(\sqrt{3}/x-1)\sin(3x) = \sqrt{3}x^2 + O(x^3) \enspace$ where $O$ is the Landau-Symbol “big-O” . Because of $\,\sqrt{3}>0\,$ your assumption is proofed for small $\,x>0\,$. For $x<0$ the inequation changes from $>$ to $<$ .

Comment: Dear @user90369: "No. Check for $x\to-0$." I don't understand what you mean. What is there to check? Obviously, both sides of the identity given by lab bhattacharjee converge to $-\infty$ if $x\to -0$, and converge to $+\infty$ if $0\to+0$. I still think my comment at 2018-03-08 08:12:50Z is correct. Would you please clarify?

Comment: @PeterHeinig: Sorry, I meant the inequality, not the identity. I was thinking in the wrong direction. My fault. Therefore you are right!

Comment: The Maple command series((sqrt(3)*cos(x)-sin(x))/sin(3*x)-sqrt(3)/(3*x)+1/3, x, 3) outputs ${\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3}}x-{\frac{4}{9}}{x}^{2}+O \left( {x}^{3}
 \right)
. $ Therefore, the inequality is true for small positive values of $x$ and false for small negative values of $x$..

Answer (score 1):

Using the identity from @labbhattacharjee, for $0 < x < \dfrac{π}{3}$ there is\begin{align*}
0 < \frac{\sin 3x}{\sqrt{3}\cos x - \sin x} &= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\sin\left( 3\left( \dfrac{π}{3} - x \right) \right)}{\sin\left( \dfrac{π}{3} - x \right)} = \frac{1}{2} \left( 3 - 4\sin^2\left( \dfrac{π}{3} - x \right) \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + 2\cos\left( \dfrac{2π}{3} - 2x \right) \right) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - \cos 2x + \sqrt{3} \sin 2x)\\
&= \sin^2 x + \sqrt{3} \sin x \cos x = \sin x (\sin x + \sqrt{3} \cos x)\\
&< x(x + \sqrt{3}) = x \cdot \frac{3 - x^2}{\sqrt{3} - x} < \frac{3x}{\sqrt{3} - x},
\end{align*}
thus$$
\frac{\sqrt{3}\cos x - \sin x}{\sin 3x} > \frac{\sqrt{3} - x}{3x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} x} - \frac{1}{3}.
$$

Comment: I think the x’s in the 4th line should be 2x.

Comment: In the expression of (1-cosx+sqrt(3)sinx)/2 all the x’s should be 2x

Comment: @user101496 Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: No problem, the rest follow with the same idea. I really like this proof. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- 
$$\frac{\sqrt3\cos x-\sin x}{\sin 3x}> \frac{\sqrt3}{3x}-\frac13\iff\frac{3x}{\sin 3x}\cdot\frac{\sqrt3\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt3-x}\gt1$$ 
Both factors in the LHS tend to $1$  and for small $x\gt0$ the first factor is greater than $1$ and the second factor is less than $1$ but it can be proved that for small $x\gt 0$ 
$$\frac{3x}{\sin 3x}\gt\frac{\sqrt3\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt3-x}$$ 
(*note that the denominator $\sqrt3-x$ is quite greater than $\sin 3x$ so you look at the numerators*)

Comment: If the first factor is greater than $1$ and the second factor is [less?] than $1$, then $${3x\over\sin3x}\gt1\gt{\sqrt3\cos x-\sin x\over\sqrt3-x}$$ so what's to prove (and how does the hint help)?

Comment: Precisely,  we would have to prove the last positive difference which could be maybe easier than other way  I wanted to indicate a possible way to solve (already $\sin 3x\lt \lt\sqrt3-x$)

Comment: @Barry Cipra: Thanks for "less" instead of "least" (my English is quite deficient).